# Check certain columns' values when using groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe'],
                'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                'Value': [1,1,1,0,0,1]})
df

 Name    ID    Value   
 Bob     1       1          
 Bob     2       1          
 Bob     3       1          
 Joe     4       0          
 Joe     5       0          
 Joe     6       1
```

The goal is to compute a `result` column. This is done by checking each group in the `name` column, in this case Bob & Joe.

So for each group, if the values in the `value` column are all `1`, the values in the `result` column for that group will be all 1. If the values are all 0, the `result` column values for that group will be all 0. And if the values are a mix of 1 and 0, the `result` column for that group will be all 0.

So the output should look like this:

```
Name    ID    Value    Result
 Bob     1       1       1   
 Bob     2       1       1   
 Bob     3       1       1   
 Joe     4       0       0   
 Joe     5       0       0   
 Joe     6       1       0
```

The difficulty is creating these groups and then checking each one.

My attempt:

```
df = df.groupby('Name')

df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Value'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `all` with `groupby+transform`:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].transform('all').astype(int)
# or df['Result'] = df['Value'].eq(1).groupby(df['Name']).transform('all').astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Name  ID  Value  Result
0  Bob   1      1       1
1  Bob   2      1       1
2  Bob   3      1       1
3  Joe   4      0       0
4  Joe   5      0       0
5  Joe   6      1       0
```

Comment: What if the values in the Value column were two other values such as 'Y' and 'N'? Rather than 1s and 0s.

Comment: @Muzz then use the solution which is commented, `df['Result'] = df['Value'].eq('Y').groupby(df['Name']).transform('all').astype(int)` or you can use replace ro replace `Y` to 1 and `N` to 0, `df=df.replace({'Y':1,'N':0})` , however I prefer the first one

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df['Result']=df.groupby('Name').Value.all().reindex(df.Name).astype(int).values
df
Out[57]: 
  Name  ID  Value  Result
0  Bob   1      1       1
1  Bob   2      1       1
2  Bob   3      1       1
3  Joe   4      0       0
4  Joe   5      0       0
5  Joe   6      1       0
```